# How to stream inserts to BigQuery with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-api-nodejs-client

I would like to use [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) to [stream rows](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll) to [Google BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/).

Digging into the [source code](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/bigquery/v2.js#L430) I found that I need a "resource" parameter. I tried several combinations and went to the source of [apirequest](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/lib/apirequest.js) but I always get the error `No rows present in the request.`

I finally managed to upload one row at a time with another [npm module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bigquery) but this module doesn't support tabledata.insertAll().

Can you give an example that shows how to use the "resource" parameter to stream inserts?

```
bigquery.tabledata.insertAll({
  auth: oauth2Client,
  'projectId': config.google.projectId,
  'datasetId': config.google.datasetId,
  'tableId': config.google.tableId,
  'resource ': {
    "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
    "rows": [
      {
        "insertId": 123456,
        "json": '{"id": 123,"name":"test1"}'
      }
    ]
  }
}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Apparently the bigquery npm module supports streaming inserts with a call to bigquery.job.load(). I would still like to use the official module however.

Comment: Is there a way to print the actual HTTP request that is being sent?

Comment: I could not find any setting in the module to enable this. And Wireshark also couldn't really help me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space after resource, have you tried removing that?

```
  'resource ': {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the issue, together with the double encoding of the JSON found by Jordan Tigani. I should have seen this myself...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're doing extra encoding of the inserted rows. They should be sent as raw json, rather than encoding the whole row as a string. That is, something like this:

```
'rows': [
  {
    'insertId': 123456,
    'json': {'id': 123,'name':'test1'}
  }
]
```

(note the difference from what you have above is just that the `{'id': 123,'name':'test1'}` line isn't quoted.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I've tried this too but this gives the same error. Looking at https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/lib/apirequest.js#L102 it seems like a "media" parameter is needed before the "resource" is even considered. I tried several combinations and even a dummy "mediaUrl" parameter and "media.body" but still the same error.

Comment: I turned out that this was the issue, together with the space after 'resource'. So thanks a lot for your help! I tried this double encoding after trying several other things and forgot to remove it again.